# How to fix this lambda expression?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I have this function for sorting by multiple user selected columns:

```
public override void Sort(SortFields sortFields)
{
    if (sortFields == null || sortFields.Count() == 0) return;

    var res = FilteredItems.OrderBy(o => o[sortFields[0].Name], sortFields[0].Ascending ? comparer : comparerDesc);

    for (int x = 1; x < sortFields.Count(); x++)
        res = res.ThenBy(o => o[sortFields[x].Name], sortFields[x].Ascending ? comparer : comparerDesc);

    FilteredItems = new BindingList<T>(res.ToList());

    if (ListChanged != null)
        ListChanged(this, new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.Reset, null));
}
```

The problem, of course, is that when res.ToList() is called x has been incremented to one greater than the highest index in the list and it throws an error. I know I could go ahead and do a ToList() after each sort but that defeats the purpose and isn't even guaranteed to sort correctly with all linq providers. I'm sure there's a simple solution to this... anyone want to tell me what it is? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you may be getting tripped up by a [closure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx) over the variable `x`.

That single variable is incremented on every iteration of the loop. It's incremented one last time, at which point it's 1 greater than the number of items in "sortFields", your conditional statement evaluates to `False`, and your `for` loop ends.

As user2864740 pointed out, and Eric states in his article:

> Closures close over variables, not over values.

So when you then call `ToList()`, your chained `ThenBy` statements retain the *final* value of the variable `x`, which was 1 greater than the highest index.

Instead, assign the incrementer to an intermediary variable inside the loop. When you call `ToList()`, the final value of `x` won't matter.

```
for (int x = 1; x < sortFields.Count(); x++)
{
    int y = x;
    res = res.ThenBy(o => o[sortFields[y].Name], sortFields[y].Ascending ? comparer : comparerDesc);
}
```

Also from Eric's article, this is (hopefully) being corrected soon, though only in `foreach` loops apparently, not `for` loops:

> In C# 5, the loop variable of a foreach will be logically inside the loop, and therefore closures will close over a fresh copy of the variable each time. The "for" loop will not be changed.

Comment: Actually I think I 'need' a closure to make this work right... just not quite sure how to do it off the top of my head but I'm sure I'll say 'duh' a soon as I see it. Not sure about that, but your code will have the same problem as mine... except instead of using x at an index that's out of range it will be using y at the top of the range for every call to the lambda expression.

Comment: @BVernon It's a closure in either case. The difference is, with this posted answer, the `y` variable is *different* or "fresh" each loop (where as the `x` variable is the same) and closures bind to variables, not values.

Comment: When the lambda gets called (when ToList() is run) it's going to use the last value for y... no different than it does for x.

Comment: @BVernon But *each* closure has a *different `y`* (which was last assigned in the loop iteration that the lambda was created in)! It will Just Work xD

Comment: Yep, you got it right... I just had a very incorrect assumption that when you declared a variable in a loop that it only allocated it once. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try

`var res = FilteredItems.OrderBy(o => o[sortFields[0].Name], sortFields[0].Ascending ? comparer : comparerDesc).ToList();`

Comment: res is IOrderedEnumerable, which has the then ThenBy() extension method. ToList() would sort x times instead of just once and wouldn't be guaranteed to be in the correct order... it would only be guaranteed to be sorted by the last field.